# Using JavaScript - loop through each <li> and add picture with a link to take to a new page in each li

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom, hyperlink

I want to loop through each `<li>` and add a picture with a link that would take to different page using JavaScrip and store all picture, link and title in array object. I used DOM

```
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "first"
        img: "img/first.jpg"
        link: "first.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "second"
        img: "img/second.jpg"
        link: "second.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third"
        img: "img/third.jpg"
        link: "third.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);

    var id = list[i].id;
    var title = list[i].title;
    var img = list[i].img;
    var link = list[i].link;
    input.appendChild(ul);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the HTML should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Supposed:

- **id** is assigned to `<li id="">`
- **title** is assigned to `<img title="">`
- **img** is assigned to `<img src="">`
- **link** is assigend to `<a href="">`

You have to create a `<img>`, `<a>` and a `<li>`. And assign the corresponding value from *list* to them.

```js
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "first",
        img: "img/first.jpg",
        link: "first.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "second",
        img: "img/second.jpg",
        link: "second.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third",
        img: "img/third.jpg",
        link: "third.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    
    img.src = list[i].img;
    img.title = list[i].title;
    
    a.href = list[i].link;    
    a.appendChild(img);
    
    li.id = list[i].id;
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.appendChild(ul);
};
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create two more elements: an `<img src="…">` within an `<a href="…" title="…" id="…">…</a>`. You can do that with the same `document.createElement` method you used. The element hierarchy is “`ul` > `li` > `a` > `img`”.

```js
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "first",
        img: "img/first.jpg",
        link: "first.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "second",
        img: "img/second.jpg",
        link: "second.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third",
        img: "img/third.jpg",
        link: "third.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var linkInfo = list[i];

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = linkInfo.img;

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = linkInfo.link;
    a.title = linkInfo.title;
    a.id = 'link-' + linkInfo.id;
    a.appendChild(img);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(a);

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.appendChild(li);

    input.appendChild(ul);
};
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
```

You also had some syntax errors in your object literals `{}`. You need commas after every `key: value` pair except the last.

I am assuming you want the ID put as the `id` attribute of each `<a>` with a format like `id="link-2"`. If that’s not what you want, just move the `a.id` line to change the `id` of the correct element with the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed besides the missing comma inside the list array that seems to be looked over is that inside of your loop you are creating a new `ul` for each of list item and then appending that to the DOM so for each list item you are making a new list this should be declared outside of the loop and then appended to the #input after the loop has finished.

```js
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "first",
        img: "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150",
        link: "first.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "second",
        img: "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150",
        link: "second.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third",
        img: "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150",
        link: "third.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var image = document.createElement('img');
  
    li.id = list[i].id;
    li.title = list[i].title;

    link.href = list[i].link;
  
    image.src = list[i].img;
    
    link.appendChild(image);
    li.appendChild(link);
    ul.appendChild(li);
};

input.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
```